# Loading jQuery with Dojo AMD loader Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I am trying to load jQuery using Dojo AMD. which is working fine when I use Jquery CDN path
Below the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="WidgetDownloadTest/lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"
data-dojo-config="async: true, packages: [
{ name: 'jquery', location: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1', main: 'jquery' }
]">
</script>
```

however if I change the jquery path to Local machine (absolute path) .
Jquery libaries(jquery-1.10.2.js,jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js,jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js) are placed in folders 'jquery/1.7.1'

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="WidgetDownloadTest/lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"
data-dojo-config="async: true, packages: [
{ name: 'jquery', location: 'jquery/1.7.1', main: 'jquery' }
]">
</script>
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Pradeep

Comment: I'm missing the question here and/or the issue itself.

Comment: Dimitri Thanks for replying.
Question is, how do i load jquery libraries from local machine using dojo AMD loader.? If I put local/absolute path it is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts mentioned in 'location' should be relative from the 'dojo.js' folder (in your case: WidgetDownloadTest/lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js).

So if for example the jquery libraries exist in 'WidgetDownloadTest/lib/jquery/1.7.1' then the 'location' parameter should be set to:

> location:'../../jquery/1.7.1'